# How many Scan Reports SonarQube Scanner can hold without configuring any additional DB to it?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, devops

While configuring SonarQube Scanner as Devops(Jenkins), 
do we need additional DB setup(like MySql,Oracle,postgresql) necessarily ?
What will be disadvantage if we will work with SonarQube scanner own Data base?
If we really need additional Db, can some one please suggest some blog url or tutorial links which having good examples.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The SonarQube Scanner itself doesn't need a database. However, the SonarQube instance it talks to very much does. Before you can successfully use the SonarQube Scanner to analyze anything, you must first set up a SonarQube instance. [The docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Setup+and+Upgrade) should help.

Comment: Thanks G.Ann !
I have went through above official document , and have done the SonarQube Instance setup, But a bit curious to know after scanning the project from Jenkins , how many scan results Sonar Qube can have(for how long it will maintain scanned project history).

Comment: @Anurag_BEHS, that's a new question. :-) [This](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Housekeeping) might help you answer it for yourself.